# 2nd Opinion on MIPS Data Hazards

Tags: assembly, mips, instructions

Can someone check if I'm right about identifying the following MIPS data hazards please?

- add  $t0,$s0,$s1 – No hazard here
- sw   $s0, 16($t0) – Hazard: $t0 will not have the value yet from the
  previous instruction
- sll  $t1,$t0,4 – No hazard here
- sw   $s0, 16($t0) – No hazard here
- sll  $t1,$t0,4 - Hazard: the previous sw would not have finished and
  would shift before it needs to be completed

I'm confident my answers for the first 3 lines are right, but I'm skeptical about the last 2 lines. Can I get a 2nd opinion?

Thanks!

Comment: `sw` does not modify any of the registers involved. Therefore the last two instructions in the sequence are `read after read` for `$t0`, which is not a hazard.

Comment: That was my 2nd thought, but I wasn't sure. Thanks so much EOF!